# Class inheritance in Javascript, call both parent and child method without super

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I'm currently facing a problem I don't know how to work around.
Working on a primitive game engine in Three.js, I'm trying make a good organization of code with inheritance.

To make it simple, I created a class called SceneManager which collects all objects in my scene.
SceneManager work with a loop that call the "update" method on each children, like so :

```js
class SceneManager {

    entities: _Entity[];

    constructor(threeScene: ThreeScene) {
        this.entities = []
    }

    update(tick: number) {
        this.entities.forEach(entity => {
            entity.update(tick)
        })
    }

}
```

Btw, for those who doesn't know the syntax, it is TypeScript, but don't worry it is Javascript anyway

Now, on my children objetcs, I would like to extends another class :RigidBody (responsible for gravity and collisions) which also have "update" method, and I would like to **call both "update" methods on parent AND children classes without calling "super"** in my child method

As exemple I have a Ball class :

```js
class Ball extends RigidBody {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    update(tick: number) {
        super.update(tick) // I don't want to call super, because I would have tons of object to handle and I would like this to be automatic

        if (this.object && this.geometry) {
            
            let radius = (this.geometry as SphereGeometry).parameters.radius
            
            let ground = __GAME__.sceneManager.get("ground")

            if (ground && ground.object) {
                if (this.object.position.y <= ground.object.position.y + radius) {
                    this.object.position.y = ground.object.position.y + radius
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And a RigidBody class :

```js
class RigidBody {

    gravity: Vector3 = new Vector3(0, -1, 0)
    acceleration: Vector3 = new Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    lastPosition: Vector3 = new Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    dt: number = 0

    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    

    update(tick: number) {
        this.accelerate()
        this.updatePosition(tick)
    }

    updatePosition(tick: number) {

        if (this.object) {
            const velocity = this.object.position.sub(this.lastPosition) 
            this.lastPosition = this.object.position.clone()
            this.object.position.add(velocity).add(this.acceleration.multiplyScalar(this.dt*this.dt))
            this.acceleration.copy(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
            this.dt += .05
        }
    }

    accelerate() {
        this.acceleration.add(this.gravity)
    } 

}
```

How should I work around this ?

Maybe I could call multiple "update" method in my scene manager like update1, update2, but it is not clean at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Template method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

In a base class define your main template method `update()`. It will handle all the common logic. Then create an abstract variant method which subclasses will have to implement for the specific logic they need:

### TypeScript code:

```typescript
abstract class Base {
  //template method
  public update(tick: number) {
    console.log(`update base; tick: ${tick}`);
    this.updateVariation();
  }

  //variant method for subclasses to define
  protected abstract updateVariation(): void;
}

class A extends Base {
  protected updateVariation() {
    console.log("updating A");
  }
}

class B extends Base {
  protected updateVariation() {
    console.log("updating B");
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.update(1);
const b = new B();
b.update(2);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gLABQCCA9ORDgLYAOq1CNOEAFgPYAmJZdAriGQBLWAn50uwagAoAlAV5kkHAHZgOyHADpkHAOYyARBKlMQuI3IDcSsu2Fhtp6TgBqwKMOnC1826QIAL4kSpQAbp7eqogs7NwIAGYcUAhggihoYDgYEBwIXDiJwqo4SnRQHNTwOFwIoJAw8OKSrh5ePn5yAFwI4RzCXAEhxCSZ6AgAggg4AB7UqlwY2NmKgRVVODV1LtTt3hC+qvJryirqmjp6hiath6r6U1YBZCMjY6gTmDPzOIvLuFOCA21WoOzu7iinWOCiIgTIsDUGi0ugMxl2JUemGeSjeoWIiPUiGACAAvAhSgB3Kb+EjAZwQ2kEpGIEBkik4amYJkgBlmHD+IA)

### JavaScript demo:

```js
"use strict";
class Base {
    //template method
    update(tick) {
        console.log(`update base; tick: ${tick}`);
        this.updateVariation();
    }
}
class A extends Base {
    updateVariation() {
        console.log("updating A");
    }
}
class B extends Base {
    updateVariation() {
        console.log("updating B");
    }
}
const a = new A();
a.update(1);
const b = new B();
b.update(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is what I was thinking about without knowing that it was a known pattern. I wanted to keep the same name of both methods to have a certain "logic" where each object I create always have "update", so i'll rename internals methods and it will be ok !